# Java socket, Is that a dead lock or what?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I have a client-server program using socket on the server side and read and write is happening in that way

```
soc = serversocket.accept();
System.out.println("Accepted");

in = new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
out = new ObjectOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());

if(in.readUTF() == null ? " " != null : !in.readUTF().equals(" "))
{
    diskinfo.setPath(in.readUTF());
}
Item[] pac = diskinfo.get();

out.writeObject(pac);
```

and similarly on the cilent(android) side...

```
Log.v("read", "item");
soc = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.2"), 3838);
output = new ObjectOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
input = new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream());

try 
{
    output.writeUTF(path);
    packets = (Item[]) input.readObject();
} 
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is that, after the connection is established the program stuck their, giving no error no exception; just stop

Comment: This if block is really hard to understand. DO you understand it yourself? Do you know how many times it reads from the input stream?

Comment: yes, i have change this now i am calling in.readObject() only once and saving the return string in a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a deadlock, you must create and flush the ObjectOutputStream first.  This is because ObjectInputStream reads the header sent by the OOS before continuing.

Comment: The deadlock you refer to only occurs if both ends create the ObjectInputStream first, which isn't happening here.

Comment: @EJP I suspect this is the correct answer to a different question. ;)

Comment: @EJP i applied both the changes that you and Peter suggest me but when i applied that you suggest me code was still not working but when i flush the OutputStream the code was working even if i undo the changes that you telling me, anyway than for you consideration and interest in this thread

Answer (score 2):

It's not a deadlock, just bad code. You keep calling readUTF() and then throwing the result away and calling it again, as though the same thing was being sent as many times as you are calling it, which it isn't. So you are *blocking,* in the redundant calls to readUTF().

So don't do that. Call it once and store the result in a variable.

And it will never return null. Check the Javadoc.